# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slack_api_token')

Tags: ios, firebase, slack, slack-api, bitrise

when i use **firebase deploy --only functions**, i have this error in Bitrise:

let slack_api_token = env.slackApiToken

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slack_api_token')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vagrant/git/functions/lib/env.js:20:54)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1894:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1855:31)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vagrant/git/functions/lib/index.js:4:13)
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you have a `.env` file in your `functions/` directory?

Comment: yes. I have **env.ts** file like  ```functions/src/env.ts```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this worked for me:

```bash
firebase functions:config:set env.slack_api_token="your_token"
```